# How to display mathematical equations?

Tags: android, html, xml, math

I have a database of this mathematical equations that I want to display them in android.

```
<span 
style="font-family:'unicode';
display: inline-block;
direction:ltr;
text-align:left">
$cos^{2}A$
</span>
```

which language is it?
how to show it as a mathematical equation in android?
where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Not sure but maybe its https://www.mathjax.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [MathView](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) is a third-party view library, which might help you display
>   math formula on Android apps

More links:

- [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)
- [jqMath](https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html)